# What do you do when travel starts to feel repetitive? How do you keep each destination exciting when the same options are available?

Tags: air-travel

What do you do when travel starts to feel repetitive? How do you keep each destination exciting when the same options are available?

Comment: I am voting this question down as it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: While there is some opinion based in this question, it is the same in most questions. There are also fact and experience based answers possible.

Comment: Go to different places. Or stay home for a while.

Comment: This is a Travel forum, heaven forbid people ask about...gasp...Travel.  There are plenty of seasoned travelers here who's *opinions* can help.

Comment: If travel isn't interesting, then why are you doing it? If you have to travel (for work, etc.), then focus on your work. But if you're traveling for pleasure and aren't enjoying it, don't do it!

Comment: @Willeke Isn't this exactly the kind of "every answer is equally valid" question that we [explicitly say to avoid asking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)?

Comment: Just to add my two cents: http://deriveapp.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding a few ideas to what Willeke already mentioned:

Do something different. You always travel alone? Book a group tour instead. You always book a package? Try to arrange something on your own. Mountains instead of a beach, nature instead of cities, whatever.

Instead of travelling, play tourist in your hometown. It's easier for me because my place is swarming with tourists in summer and it's easy to follow their steps, but I'm sure there's some museum to see, hike to take or whatever near your hometown.

Try geocaching. I often do it when travelling because I feel it takes me off the main tourist routes - just a little, but it's amazing what you get to see (in 2012 I spent 3 months in Helsinki but did no caching. In 2013 I came back and did some caching - I was amazed by the new places around the city I discovered!).

Take a moment (or more) to figure what YOUR interests are. I'm not interested in arts, museums all look the same to me. But I can watch a town from above for hours and hours, it's not boring at all :) .

Answer (score 3):

Change off between bigger and smaller towns, visit villages, do a few days of walking or join a sailing tour or cruise, use trains or buses if you otherwise would travel by car or plane.

In each city/town look for those things that are unique for that place, do your homework before arriving so you know what to look for.
Also read up on the next few locations before you do what is a small experience in one city where there is a better/bigger experience of the same kind in the next stop.

And take a break from traveling to have a holiday if you go on for a longer time. Holiday being what you would do for your yearly break from work, or just a few days chilling out on a beach, or going skiing if traveling in winter.